# Xcode Swift pass closure as parameter on init()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to pass Closure as parameter on initialization, like Kotlin block passing.
but "Variable 'self.calendarView' captured by a closure before being initialized" occurred.
how can fix it..?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let calendarView : MyDateCalendarView
    func turnOnDailyPlanView(_ dateString : String){
        print(dateString)
    }
    init(){
        calendarView = MyDateCalendarView(year: 2021, month: 10)
        {
            (str : String) -> Void in
            turnOnDailyPlanView(str)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: declare your calendarView as Optionals. for ex:- `let calendarView : MyDateCalendarView?` or `let calendarView : MyDateCalendarView? = nil` or even `let calendarView : MyDateCalendarView!`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use instance methods until the instance has been initialized.

One solution is to use an implicitly unwrapped optional…

```swift
private(set) var calendarView: MyDateCalendarView!

init() {
  calendarView = MyDateCalendarView(
    year: 2021,
    month: 10,
    whateverTheClosureIsCalled: turnOnDailyPlanView
  )
}
```

…but do you need that? Your method doesn't use any instance information. It could be static.

```swift
static func turnOnDailyPlanView(_ dateString: String) {
  print(dateString)
}
  
init() {
  calendarView = MyDateCalendarView(
    year: 2021,
    month: 10,
    whateverTheClosureIsCalled: Self.turnOnDailyPlanView
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I made my view struct as optional type. That function will do more operation about modifying view design.